# laravel 8.83.5 displays an error Target class [PostsController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Am new to Laravel and am using Laravel 8.83.5. I created a new controller called Posts PostsController using php artisan and I also created a new directory called posts in the layouts directory but when I try accessing that file using http://127.0.0.1:8000/p I get an error that TIlluminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [PostsController] does not exist.

here is my web.php file

```
<?php
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
// use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
Route::get('/',function(){
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/p','PostsController@create');

Route::get('/profile/{user}','ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');
```

here is the file called create.blade.php i want to display when I run http://127.0.0.1:8000/p

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
```

@endsection

and here is my postsController file
<?php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
public function create(){
    return view('posts.create');
}
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php 
    //in web.php  namespace your Posts Controller
    use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;
    
   Route::get('/posts',[PostsController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
```

try this out if works

Comment: ```PostsController::class``` syntax is IDE Friendly to jump between classes instead of old ```Route::get('/posts','PostsController@create');```

Comment: I tried it but i get this error BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::index does not exist.

Comment: u mean i use  use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController; on web.php instead of use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; and use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Comment: Am calling index file in the view directory

Comment: how can i fix it should i create indexController file in controllers directory